# Technology stack used by Web Whatapp [Chrome]

Tags: google-chrome, whatsapp

Just curious to know, what technology **WhatApp** engineering guys are using for https://web.whatsapp.com/ that work specific to Chrome Browser.

1. If you sync your mobile to chrome(mirroring) then what `protocol` they used to get all chat of mobile on Chrome even you are not in same network.
2. And, if you disconnect your Whatapp from Wifi or Internet, then it throws message called **"Phone not connected"** though I can see any `ajax` or `websocket` call from Chrome Developer Tools.

Answer (score -2):

Not 100% sure about their technologies, But they are using the advantages of HTML5 + Web Socket